# When Overwriting a variable, what happens to the old reference?

Tags: javascript, variables, memory, while-loop, overwrite

I'm working on a probabilistic project with multiple variables that are re-written hundreds of thousands of times (if not millions) each time the program runs in JS.
But I'm getting a Memory shortage error, I suspect that the *previous values* of the variables continued to be stored in my memory, and each time the *while()* loop is repeated, it just gets storing *previous versions* of the variable.

Here is an over-simplified example of what I mean:

```
var loop_counter = 0;
var loop_max = 1000000; /// a million loops as an example

var variable = 1;
var modifier = 1.05;

while(loop_counter < loop_max){

variable = (variable * modifier);

loop_counter += 1;
} /// while() ends after variable is "modified" 1,000,000 times

console.log(variable);
```

Ok, so in this example we have "variable" which value is 1. We also have "modifier" that is "modifier". In this simplified example, in each while() "loop", "variable" increases 5% it's value in a geometric sequence. The final *"variable"* value would be hyper-long, which if the previous versions of  *"variable"* continue to be stored somewhere in the Memory junk, could take a great chunk of the Memory.

My questions are:

A) Each time the *while()* loop repeats, is the *"variable"* value of the previous loop stored? (At least temporarily?)

If yes:

A.1) For how long is it stored?

A.2) Is there a way to optimize this "junk variable storage management" in order to not fill out the Memory while the program is running?

If not:

B) Any ideas on what could be causing the shortage of Memory based on the simplified example?

Take into account the actual program include thousands of variables that in fundamental terms do the same function that the example showed above in the same while() loop.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Numbers don't get "long". Numbers are all fixed size around a 64-bit core no matter how big or small the contained numeric value is.

Comment: Also, numbers are primitive values, and don't have references: they are stored directly into the variable. When you overwrite a number, the old value is instantly gone. So no, this simplified example cannot run out of memory. You would need more complex objects.

Comment: Also multiplying by 1.05 a million times will overflow to `Infinity`.